# DirectQuery vs. Import for frequently changing data

Tags: powerbi

According to the Microsoft documentation, DirectQuery should be used when data is changing frequently and reports must reflect the latest data (see below). I don't understand why this is the case. Importing data can retrieve the same frequently changing data that DirectQuery can. I don't see why DirectQuery would be preferred.

*If your goals can't be met by importing data, then consider using DirectQuery. For example, if the data is changing frequently and reports must reflect the latest data, DirectQuery may be best.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import isn't live, so your data will only be as fresh as the last refresh and if you don't have a premium license, then your automatic refreshes are capped at 8/day. I think premium is more like 48, but still not live.

The other major difference is that DirectQuery allows you to connect to huge datasets without having to pull down all the data. It only pulls what it needs when it needs it.

Comment: So I assume DQ is ‘live’? What does this mean? Is data constantly refreshed?

Comment: Whenever you make a change to a visual, it pings the source data and pulls in only the necessary rows. Check out the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-directquery-about